# CreateFromStream in Android returning null for certain url

Tags: android

```
public class TestButton extends Activity {   
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    ImageButton imgBtn;   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
        //String url = "http://thenextweb.com/apps/files/2010/03/google_logo.jpg";
        String url1 = "http://trueslant.com/michaelshermer/files/2010/03/evil-google.jpg";
        Drawable drawable = LoadImage(url1);
        imgBtn.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    private Drawable LoadImage(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code snippet which I use to load image from web into ImageButton. Most of the images get displayed , but certain urls like the one above i.e. url1 , Drawable.createFromStream returns null !! What is the reason and how to avoid it or overcome  this problem ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've stumbled upon same problem today. And found an answer, luckily :) There is a [bug in SDK, described more or less on that google groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4ed17d7e48899b26/).

Workaround that worked for me is:

```
     private static final int BUFFER_IO_SIZE = 8000;

     private Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(final String url) {
        try {
            // Addresses bug in SDK :
            // http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4ed17d7e48899b26/
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(baos, BUFFER_IO_SIZE);
            copy(bis, bos);
            bos.flush();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle it properly
        }
    }

    private void copy(final InputStream bis, final OutputStream baos) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        int l;
        while ((l = bis.read(buf)) >= 0) baos.write(buf, 0, l);
    }
```

And make sure not to set buffers size to more than 8k, because OS will use default size instead of the one you set (logging that of course, but it took me a while to notice that ;) ).

Comment: That bug was in version 1.0 of Android, is it still around in 2.x? In my tests it appears to be the case, but I'm looking for official confirmation from Google. Also, in your code what do you set BUFFER_IO_SIZE to?

Comment: @ThomasW Can't tell for sure. Two things I'm certain about are that it has the same behavior and the same fix worked for me in 2.1 and 2.2 both on emulator and device. I'll update my answer to include BUFFER_IO_SIZE value.

Comment: You, my man, are a genius.  Saved me a b-load of time hunting this down! I'm surprised the bug still exists.  In any case, thanks for this!  Is it any more efficient using a bitmap vs. drawable?

Comment: If you set the buffer size to `BUFFER_IO_SIZE ` in your copy method, you don't need the `BufferedOutputStream` anymore, as it will try to fill its own buffer automaticly

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is using FlushedInputStream http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066